# Framework7 with Cordova

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

I have created a very simple website using Framework7 and bundled it with Cordova. When I run it on my mobile as an app, it works but it does not navigate to another page using link (with our without router).

I opened the file from my browser using file:// and same problem. However when I server the files through an Http server, I can browse it on browser and navigate to  other page using links.

I understand that is because Cordova internally open the file in Webview using file:// protocol and Framework7 expects the files are being served using an Http server.

Can anyone guide me what to do, I don't want to use Vue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some code ?

Comment: If you use multiple HTML-pages you run in some problems. Create a single page app (SPA) and read the documentation before: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/guide/next/index.html

Comment: @Djiggy I used this: https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-template-single-view and copied www folder in cordova project.